# Wordpress Loop: how to wrap each 3 posts into a div?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach

I'm trying this:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div>
            <?php $counter=3; ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php $counter++; ?>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it's not working! :/
Thank you!

Comment: I think this would be the easiest way to do this: stackoverflow.com/questions/28247770/loop-through-wordpress-posts-and-wrap-each-x-post-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support guys! :) 
I tried both solutions but didn't work,
I ended up with this and works perfectly!

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6'); ?>

<?php $variable=0;?>

<div>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if(($variable+1)<4){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'colaborador-link', true); ?>" target="blank">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
<?php $variable+=1; ?>
<?php }else{ ?>
<?php $variable=1; ?>
</div>

<div>
<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'colaborador-link', true); ?>" target="blank">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
<?php }?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it with wordpress so i'm not 100% sure it'll work. 
The idea is to use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator (see an example that matches your needs here  http://codepad.org/78d2aAKp)

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<!-- Your div starts here -->
<div>
<?php 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post();
        $counter = 0;
        if($counter%3 == 0 && $counter > 0):
?>
<!--Close and then open the div-->
</div><div>
<?php 
        endif;
?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--/Your div ends here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php query_posts('cat=6'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $counter=0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if($counter%3==0) : ?>        
<div>
        <?php $counter=3; ?>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php $counter++; ?>
</div>
<?php else: 
//Some code for other posts..
endif;
?>
<?php $counter++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```